# Deleting files using wildcards

Tags: powershell, batch

I have hundreds of files named like `SageAccts Company Name 2018-06-21 00-00-10`.

The time and date are in the title. I wish to delete all files that do not have a date of `2018-**-05`, `2018-**-15` or `2018-**-28`.

I do not have huge coding experience so PowerShell or a batch file would be best.

Comment: Can you also work with the modifying time/date of the file, rather than a portion of the filename? If so, you can use forfiles to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Best you first filter with a [Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/3pyWhg/1) and use a (capture group) to grep the day,
to then exclude your special days `05|15|28`

You didn't specify an extension so neither will I.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\24\SU_1342824.ps1
#Requires -Version 3.0
Push-Location "X:\Folder\to\start"

$RE = [RegEx]'^SageAccts Company Name 2018-[01][0-9]-([0-3][0-9]) [0-2][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]$'
##                                    year-  month  -(  day     )    hour   - minute   -  second

Get-ChildItem 'SageAccts Company Name 2018-*' -File |
  Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match $RE} |
    Where-Object {$Matches[1] -notmatch '05|15|28' }|
      Remove-Item -Whatif
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet

```
## to generate test files
1..30|%{new-Item -ItemType file -path ("SageAccts Company Name 2018-06-{0:00} 00-00-10.txt" -f $_)}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in PowerShell is a Regular Expression match that uses a negative lookbehind, denoted by `?(<!)`, to exclude the desired days.

```
Get-ChildItem "SageAccts Company Name *" | ?{ $_ -match '2018-(?:0\d|1[1,2])-(?:[0-2]\d|[3][0,1])(?<!05|15|28)' } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

1. The wildcard filter with Get-ChildItem provides limiting of the file
   information retrieved. Get-ChildItem does not support regular expressions 
   directly.
2. The `?{}` is shorthand for the Where-Object commandlet.
3. The provided regular expression used with the `-match` operator will
   get the list of files that you want.
4. The What-If switch on Remove-Item prevents the removal from being
   performed while reporting what would occur. It allows you to review
   the results before actually doing it. If everything looks good just
   remove the `-What-If` and run it again.

   You can always use Get-Help to find out more about a commandlet.